# Error ejecutando Log Shipping

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

He configurado log shipping para 36 bases de datos en dos servidores Lenovo, de características físicas muy similares, la misma versión de SO (Windows Server 2018) y SQL Server (2016), tiene una diferencia de tiempo entre cada base de datos de 10 minutos y repite la misma base de datos a las 6 horas... Ahora bien, en algún momento NO especifico del día falla el Job del RESTORE, en alguna base de datos que su ciclo previo ya había funcionado. Uno de los Errores es el siguiente;

- Error: No se pudo aplicar el archivo de copia de seguridad de registros 'XXX_20210829185000.trn' a la base de datos secundaria 'XXX'.(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.LogShipping)
- Error: Error al procesar el registro de la base de datos 'XXX'. Si es posible restaure la base de datos a partir de una copia de seguridad. Si no dispone de una copia de seguridad puede ser necesario generar de nuevo el registro.
  Se ha producido un error durante la recuperación que impide reiniciar la base de datos 'XXX' (21:0). Diagnostique los errores de recuperación y corríjalos o restaure desde una copia de seguridad en buen estado. Si los errores no se han corregido o se espera que haya errores póngase en contacto con el soporte técnico.
  Fin anómalo de RESTORE LOG. Se han procesado 0 páginas para la base de datos 'XXX' archivo 'XXX_Data' en el archivo 1. Se han procesado 1 páginas para la base de datos 'XXX' archivo 'XXX_Log' en el archivo 1.(.Net SqlClient Data Provider)
- Error: No se pudo registrar el historial/mensaje de error.(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.LogShipping)
- Error: ExecuteNonQuery requiere una Connection abierta y disponible. El estado actual de la conexión es cerrada.(System.Data)
  Omitiendo el archivo de copia de seguridad de registros 'XXX_20210829185000.trn' de la base de datos secundaria 'XXX' porque no pudo comprobarse dicho archivo.
- Error: No se pudo registrar el historial/mensaje de error. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.LogShipping)
- Error: ExecuteNonQuery requiere una Connection abierta y disponible. El estado actual de la conexión es cerrada.(System.Data)
- Error: Error al restaurar el modo de acceso a la base de datos.(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.LogShipping)
- Error: ExecuteScalar requiere una Connection abierta y disponible. El estado actual de la conexión es cerrada.(System.Data)
- Error: No se pudo registrar el historial/mensaje de error.(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.LogShipping)
- Error: ExecuteNonQuery requiere una Connection abierta y disponible. El estado actual de la conexión es cerrada.(System.Data)
- Error: Error al restaurar el modo de acceso a la base de datos.(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.LogShipping)
- Error: ExecuteScalar requiere una Connection abierta y disponible. El estado actual de la conexión es cerrada.(System.Data)
- Error: No se pudo registrar el historial/mensaje de error.(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.LogShipping)
- Error: ExecuteNonQuery requiere una Connection abierta y disponible. El estado actual de la conexión es cerrada.(System.Data)
  Eliminando archivos antiguos de copia de seguridad de registros. Base de datos principal: 'XXX'
- Error: No se pudo registrar el historial/mensaje de error.(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.LogShipping)
- Error: ExecuteNonQuery requiere una Connection abierta y disponible. El estado actual de la conexión es cerrada.(System.Data)
  Eliminando archivo de copia de seguridad de registros. Archivo: 'XXX_20210824142000.trn' Hora de £ltima escritura (UTC): '24/08/2021 14:20:00'
- Error: No se pudo registrar el historial/mensaje de error.(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.

Alguien tiene una pista???

Comment: Vi que un error parecido a este en MSSQL 2019 lo resolvían instalando el Cumulative Update 1... ¿has probado actualizar tus MSSQL a 2016 CU 6 o superior?

Comment: Buscando rápidamente, también existen reportes de errores de log shipping debido a permisos insuficientes del SQLAgent.

Comment: Arriel, definitivamente no puede ser un tema de permisos, porque la falla es aleatoria en muy pocas bases de datos (2 o 3 de 36), y en diferentes horarios. Incluso la falla se presenta en bases de  datos que venían funcionando los jobs bien. De cualquier manera, gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Alfabravo, revisaré las actualizaciones que puede tener pendiente. Gracias!